# Where do the files of a custom WP CLI Command reside?

Tags: wp-cli

I want to create a custom WP CLI command and I have read the documentation but I just don't understand for the life of me how this works.

Do I need to declare it before in my config file where they are gonna go?

Is it a PHP file? If so, I need to declare it put it anywhere inside my theme?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: there is a chapter "Extending" here https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/#extending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the PHP anywhere in your plugin, or a file that's included into your plugin,  the same as you would any other code for extending any part of WordPress in a plugin. The only thing you need to do is check that `WP_CLI` exists before using any of the WP CLI API:

```
if ( defined( 'WP_CLI' ) && WP_CLI ) {
    // WP_CLI::add_command etc.
}
```

Comment: Can I include this as a theme file and call it within functions.php?

Comment: Yes. It will work in themes too.